# Linker error: C/C++ Extensions for python

Tags: python, c++, c, python-3.x

As my title kind of says, I'm trying to develop a C extension for Python. I followed this tutorial here and I ran the setup.py script. How ever when I run the python interpreter and try to import my newly created module, I get a linker error undefined symbol: py_BuildValue. I also tryed to compile it my self and I got the same errors plus an error saying Py_InitModule3 is undefined. I have installed both python3.2-dev and python3-dev. Here is my test.c code:

```
#include <python3.2/Python.h>
static PyObject* Test(PyObject* self){
    return py_BuildValue("s","This is a test and my first trip into the world of python bindings!!");
}

static PyMethodDef test_funcs[] ={{"testExtensions",(PyCFunction)Test, METH_NOARGS,"This is my First Extension!!"},{NULL}};

 void initTest(void){
    Py_InitModule3("Test", test_funcs, "Extension module example!");
}
```

And my setup.py code:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name='Test', version='1.0',  \
    ext_modules=[Extension('Test', ['test.c'])])
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the function is called `Py_BuildValue` rather than `py_BuildValue`. C is case sensitive. If you check further up in your compile messages, you probably also have a warning there about the function being implicitly declared.

Comment: Oh hmm. I was following a tutorial. Infact the cody is copied and pasted. But I guess that could be it Thanks.

Comment: I followed up on this. I have been known do stupid things like that but it would appear that's not the issue.

Comment: @rady: Are you sure it's the same error? When I try to compile your code but correct the `Py_BuildValue` capitalization, the error moves to build about `Py_InitModule3` instead, which is understandable since that's a Python 2 function, while at appears you're trying to compile for Python 3.

Comment: it is the second error. How would I adapt this for python3